# is there a quota for accessing a public Google calendar RSS feed?

Tags: google-calendar-api

i am accessing a public google calendar via its RSS feed. the URL looks something like the following one

```
https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/{myCalendarId}/public/full-noattendees?alt=json
```

i was now wondering if there is a quota for this access (maybe per device??). if yes: what's the max access count per day and where can i see how much is left and where can i request more in case i needed to. i guess i had to add a client id or so in that case.

btw: i am not using any API or authentication. i just call the URL and parse the result myself.

thanks
Simon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, i tried it now with a simple loop. i've loaded the page on two consecutive days 20,000 times per day. the query did never get blocked, so it looks like there is no quota on public calendar access.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Google does impose a limit of 10,000 "hits" per day. You can read more information about quotas and limits here:
https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar-resource/#api_limits_and_quotas
https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/pricing

Comment: not sure, but it seems that this quotas are just for authenticated access. i've tried to exceed it with the public url, and could access it way more then 10,000 times a day.